# What is the correct way to represent the CNOT gate on a circuit drawing where the target is an arbitrary qubit in a register?

Tags: terminology-and-notation

Suppose we have a circuit composed of a single ancillary qubit and a $|{\psi}\rangle$ registry with n qubits. I want to draw a CNOT controlled on the ancilla and targeted on the last qubit of the $|{\psi}\rangle$ registry. Below I have drawn two examples where "a)" would require clarification in the text, and "b)" is self-explanatory, but visually more cumbersome. Is there a proper way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Is there a better way? Not that I know of. I think your solution b) looks fine to my eyes. The only option you have here is to perhaps maintain $\psi$ as a single line and expand multi-line just around that gate. But this may be hard to write, depending on which (Latex?) package you use .

Comment: So far, I have seen b) several times, while I have never seen a).

Comment: What is "proper" seems like it might be a matter of opinion. At least to me it sounds pretty normative, as opposed to objective. But, that being said, it seems to me like option a) is so ripe for confusion that it should probably never be used. Therefore, my vote is for option b).

Comment: If you want to draw one wire, one options is to replace the target with $I_{n-1}\otimes X$ in a box.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example (controlled unitary instead of controlled not) from Quantum Information and Computation by Nielsen and Chuang (the chapter entitled "The quantum Fourier transform and its applications"). Looks like your option b), but I find the arrangement a bit clearer since the dots are more spaced out and closer to the repeated Qubits. [image]

I wouldn't go with option a), because it won't be clear at a glance what the /n means for many people (myself included).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).